# Python: pop() returning py list, not my object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to code an exercise to solve the Queen Puzzle (yes, typical, I know) on Python. I've made a class called `Queens` for board state that takes in the length of each side and the list of queens, if any.

In the main program, I have a `list` of `Queens` called `frontier`, which is then popped one by one. However, the result I get from popping seems to be of type `list`, and not `Queens` as expected!

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Code snippet:

```
from queens import Queens

def search(n, debug=False, max=6):
    frontier = [Queens(n, [])] # queue of states to explore
    while frontier != []:
        check = frontier.pop()
        print(type(check))
    if debug:
        print(str(numSolutions) + " | Checking:")
        print(check)
    v = check.validate()
    # EDIT: added more of the code; problem seems to arise here
    if v == 0:
        if debug:
            print("Solution!")
        numSolutions += 1
        if n <= max:
            solutions.append(check)
    elif v > 0:
        if debug:
            print(str(v) + " more")
        frontier.append(check.branch())
    else:
        if debug:
            print("Invalid state")
        pass
```

expected output:

```
<class 'queens.Queens'>
```

actual output:

```
<class 'queens.Queens'>
<class 'list'>
```

(yes, the one type statement printed 2 lines)

EDIT: Since there seems to be no problem with the main code, here's the file in which I defined the class:

```
import array
import copy
class Queens:
    __slots__ = ["n", "qlist"]

    def __init__(self, n, qa=None):
        self.n = n # store for print function
        if qa == None:
            self.qlist = array.array("h")
        elif type(qa) == list:
            self.qlist = array.array("h", qa)
        else:
            assert type(qa) == array.array
            self.qlist = qa # list of positions for each line

    def __str__(self):
        out = ""
        for q in range(self.n):
            if q == 0:
                out += "|"
            else:
                out += "\n|"
            for space in range(self.n):
                if q < len(self.qlist) and space == self.qlist[q]:
                    out += "Q|"
                else:
                    out += " |"
        return out

    def branch(self):
        out = []
        for x in range(self.n):
            if x not in self.qlist:
                qlist = copy.deepcopy(self.qlist)
                qlist.append(x)
                out.append(Queens(self.n, qlist))
        return out

    def validate(self):
        for y in range(len(self.qlist)):
            # don't need to check horizontal; 
            # data structure doesn't let you place them
            # don't need to check vertical;
            # branching eliminates those
            # check diagonals
            for y2 in range(len(self.qlist)):
                if y != y2:
                    expected = self.qlist[y] - y + y2
                    if 0 <= expected < self.n and self.qlist[y2] == expected:
                        return -1
                    expected = self.qlist[y] + y - y2
                    if 0 <= expected < self.n and self.qlist[y2] == expected:
                        return -1
        return self.n - len(self.qlist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queens(4)
    print(q.validate())
    q = Queens(4, [0, 1, 2])
    print(q.validate())
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Can you post Queens?

Comment: python 3 or 2.x ?

Comment: @denis_lor Appended queens.py.

Comment: @ddor254 *stares at the camera like I'm in The Office*

Comment: It's still not a MCVE and I still can't repro the problem.

Comment: Copied your entire code. Copied search. Added `search(4)` to run. Only get one output, and no list

Comment: @haley did not understand what you want

Comment: Added more of the code, because commenting out the rest made the program run as intended. The problem seems to start with ``if v == 0:``

Comment: We cannot run this code. Both `numSolutions` and `solutions` are undefined. You need to try to create a code snippet that we can copy+paste with your bug, because currently this error is likely happening somewhere completely different from where you think it's occurring.

Comment: Further: We need an input to `search()` that errors

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. The problem happened only after `frontier.append(check.branch())`. `branch()` returns a `list` of `queens`. I thought I was appending several `queens` to `frontier`, but I was, in fact, appending a `list` of `queens` to `frontier`. Changing `append` to `extend` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you append to your `frontier` the result of `.branch(..)` and you re-iterate you get an array back (list). Which is being printed after the loop continues to the next step.

```
def branch(self):
        out = []
        for x in range(self.n):
            if x not in self.qlist:
                qlist = copy.deepcopy(self.qlist)
                qlist.append(x)
                out.append(Queens(self.n, qlist))
        return out
```

Comment: What does "Queens is as well an array" mean?